# How to find duplicate junit tests

Tags: java, junit

Is there way to find duplicate tests to clean up redundant tests?

To explain:

```
public class Sut {
    public void method() {}
    public void methodB() {}
    public void methodC() {}
}

public class TestA {
    public void testMethod() {}
    public void testMethodB() {}
}

public class TestB {
    public void testMethodblablahB() {} // it has a different set of code other than testMethodB() 
// but it covers the same code of methodB
    public void testMethodC() {}
}
```

from the code testMethodblablahB, it might not be immediately obvious both testMethodB and testMethodblahblah, gives the same coverage for the methodB. I can probably do that by analyzing using pen/paper or debugging.

Is there any automated way of determining this? May be some sort of graph algorithm?

Comment: It's pretty normal to test a method more than once.  I wouldn't necessarily consolidate those or call them redundant.

Comment: Can't agree with that. When tests need updated because of requirement changes, there are twice the efforts. Same is true if there is a library update required, ie say Junit4 to Junit5, the efforts are duplicated.